# Illegal Instruction arises in iterator with else statement

Tags: c++, linux, iterator

I have the following code snippet (it's part of a much larger application), which works fine:

```
// Find the signal with SignalId in the map m_isMap
InputSignalMap::iterator it = m_isMap.find(evt.SignalId());
if (it != m_isMap.end())
{
    Signal *sns = evt.GetSignal();
    it->second->SignalUpdate(*sns);
    delete sns;
}
```

However, when I attempt to add/append the following code to the above if-statement block:

```
else
{
    //log error - signal not found
}
```

and the first code snippet fires (signal is found), it reaches the `delete sns;` and dies, giving me an SIGILL/illegal instruction for a reason. I've run it with gdb and valgrind, but there doesn't appear to be much information about the issue.

What I don't quite understand is why the first block *without* the else-statement works without triggering the illegal instruction, but with the else-statement in place, the illegal instruction appears.

Is there something obvious I'm missing? Is the problem to do with the iterator bit, or would my other methods (not supplied here) be the more likely culprit? Help? I've no idea.

Comment: If you isolate this code into a minimal compilable example, and it doesn't occur, you may have a good candidate for your compiler producing bad instruction erroneously (illegal instruction is a good hint, but if you have UB elsewhere in your code it's not impossible...)  Another thing you can try is making that separate `void` returning function and place a return after the delete, and just letting the else block not be there.  But as it sits, there's nothing obviously wrong with your code, and because we don't have a reproduction case, it's impossible for us to test it.

Comment: Seems to me (unless it's a compiler problem) there is a problem in your code that by luck survives but crashes when some other code (in this case, your `else` statement) is included. Have you tried different optimization switches to see if it crashes (eg, -O1, -O2, etc) even without the `else`?

Comment: It does sound like you have a wayward pointer and storing into its referent you're stomping on the stack and then you return to Nowheristan where you get an illegal instruction. Sort of. Try to reduce reliance on raw pointers.

Comment: Can you run `disass /m` in `gdb` to show us the code around the illegal instruction?